# jQuery datepicker issue when saving to MS Access database

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a datepicker on my ASP.NET C# web form and I want to save this value to MS Access database. But when I press a button to save it, I get the error: "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0."

Could someone help me? Thanks

My date picker:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
         beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
         minDate: 0,
         maxDate: "+2M",
         dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });
});

<input type="text" id="datepicker" readonly="readonly" />
```

Code behind:

```
 AccessDataSource2.Insert();
 AccessDataSource2.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct format of using asp.net with jquery ui is this:

```
  $(function () {
      $("#<%=txtDate.ClientID%>").datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
            minDate: "+10D",
            maxDate: "+2M",
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'  
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date should be of format 'dd/mm/yyyy' as MS Access doesn't support 'dd/mm/yy'.
If that is not helping, check your systems date format. If it's mm/dd/yyyy, then you need to change datepicker date format accordingly. Hope that helps.